# Invalid Code Signing Entitlements

Tags: iphone, xcode

I ve followed all the procedure that app store support placed for help yet when ever i sumit the app after upload the status becomes "invalid binary" with following msg in the mail.

```
Invalid Code Signing Entitlements - Your application bundle's signature contains ubiquity code signing entitlements that are not supported.

Specifically, value "( 79FWT492R4.* )" for key "com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers" in is not supported.
```

I will be thankful if someone help

Thanks
MGD

Comment: thanks for ur reply but i followed the recommended procedure mentioned at the apple developer support for making App ID (com.domainname.appname)

Comment: Are you trying to use iCloud?

Comment: Roger i ve fixed it already by unchecking the icloud :D

Comment: Cool - so my original comment was correct then ;-) As you will see when you read that thread, iCloud is specifically mentioned.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well i really dont know why Apple has set so many complications for the app submission.Now coming towards the solution,  What i did was, I used the same APP ID but i reconfigured it by **unchecking** the **iCloud** option, then i renewed the provision and distribution profiles downloaded them, deleted the old profiles from the xcode organizer added the new ones (those i downloaded after renew), first my app started giving error during the that "key does not match .... "  then i went to the built info of the target there i simply set "iphone distribution" in code signing, Thats it i build the app and uploaded via organizer, and it went with the status "Waiting for Review" :)

Cheers 
MGD

Comment: I'd love to do this, but there doesn't seem to be an option to uncheck iCloud .... ?

Comment: Thank you, and I hope Xamarin will release some "wizard tool" for obtaining and installing the right certificates from Apple. Only Miguel can save us from the "PROVISIONING HELL" Apple brought to us.

Answer (score 5):

Just to clarify the answer, which I found confusing. I had ths problem just now (October 2011) and solved it quickly. 
I thought I had to revoke my own distribution certificate, but this clarifying note saved me (can't find the source right now but THANK YOU)

1. Go to App IDs in the provisioning portal. Scroll to the bottom. Click configure on the row that represents your app’s ID. Uncheck Enable for iCloud. Click Done.

--
Now you can just regenerate your distro provisioning prof (no need to create a new one) and redownload it into Xcode, reubild and resubmit. i hope this helps people

Answer (score 3):

There is indeed no more option to disable iCloud in Provisioning Portal. But apparently Apple has noticed that the iCloud entitlements in distribution certificates may cause trouble during submission and has recently REMOVED these entitlements from the certificates again.

So help is near: Just re-create your distribution certificate and you'll see that it doesn't contain the offending keys any more. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Under the Code Signing section in my Build Settings, Xcode had selected iOS Developer for Release instead of iOS Distribution. Selecting the correct distribution profile for Release resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to remove the provisioning profile entries.  Evidently in addition to the Code Signing entries, now there are also Provisioning Profile entries and mine was stuck on an old version or something.  Clearing that fixed the problem.