# invalid binary error in iTunes connect

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am trying to upload my app on appstore. Whenever I submit the app successfully,it shows Invalid binary in iTunes connect.

I tried various ways suggested to avoid this error in the other posts.

like I checked all icon images.

I created entire app again.

Revoked and recreated certificates and provisioning profiles.

Still its giving me same error. it does not give any error while building app or while submitting app. only after submitting it shows invalid binary. can any one help me in this?

does creating new id at iTunes connect will work? but i do not want to change the name of the app. whenever i try to delete app from iTunes connect it gives me warning that this app name can not be used in future for any  application.

Comment: Are you making build for iOS or Simulator?

Comment: why my question is down voted? i really did everything read all blog posts. but it is still happening that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally it worked!

I revoked all certificates, and created new. then Recreated new app id and provisioning. created new app id in iTunes store and uploaded application. and now it is showing me Waiting for Review status.

Answer (score 1):

If you have several distribution certificates, check whether you are selecting the same distribution certificate when submitting the app and the certification which you have used to build the application. This might cause to your problem.

Comment: i have only certificate and distribution provisioning profile

Comment: Didn't you receive any mail from apple regarding this issue?

Comment: yes i received, it says Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. but i do not get any provisioning error  while building app

Comment: Please check this discussion. it's same as yours. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427735/invalid-code-signing-entitlements)

Comment: hey, i checked that post. I recreated the certificates andy provisioning. but still i am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me, no errors in the validation nor submission and no resolution center.
But later i have found that they have sent an email to the account owner's email, and registered developer

Answer (score 0):

The email I received from Apple had clear language in it corresponding to the change I needed to make. I was submitting a build with an Apple Watch app written in Swift. I had to target 7.0 because I was using Swift. I made this change and the binary was accepted and approved within hours.

Comment: would you please elaborate ? I have an apple watch extension written in objective-c and my target is iOS 7.1 would that be the reason I'm getting this error ? ( no emails received from apple )