# Invalid Binary Error When post a build on Test Flight with iTunes

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, testflight

When i have post a Beta Build on Test Flight in iTunes account. I have got a error Invalid Binary (On Status). I have added build on Pre release also added Internal & External Tester on that. Still i am facing same issue. So anyone can explain me this issue from Test Flight with iTunes or Certificate. I have also attached screenshot with this bug.

Comment: did you solve this error?

Comment: no ?i didn't received any answer .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765443/invalid-binary-error-in-itunes-connect take a look