# Please help to solve Invalid Binary issue

Tags: iphone, binary, submission

Just received this from app store today.

> Dear Developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent binary
>   submission for "KwikTap Mobile". Before your app can be reviewed, the
>   following issues must be corrected:
>
> Invalid Code Signing Entitlements - The signature for your app bundle
>   contains entitlement values that are not supported.
>
> Specifically, value "4J8CVAF9MB.*" for key
>   "com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier" in QR Code Scanner
>   is not supported.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page
>   and click Ready to Upload Binary. Continue through the submission
>   process until the app status is Waiting for Upload and then use
>   Application Loader to upload the corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The iTunes Store Team

---

Is there anyone who can help in this matter? Your feedback will be most welcomed

Kindest Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6427735/398460

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "." for the "com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier" entitlement?

Like "4J8CVAF9MB.com.example.myapp".

Also have you checked that "4J8CVAF9MB" is your exact team id?